# WP7 - Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I am trying to add items into Dictionary. The following code I am using to add the values into Dictionary.

```
Console.WriteLine("selectedCategories.Count==> " + selectedCategories.Count);
selectedCategoryMap = new Dictionary<String, Category>();
     if (selectedCategories != null)
       {
          foreach (Category category in selectedCategories)
            {
               selectedCategoryMap.Add(category.getCategoryID(), category);
            }
       }
```

I can insert upto 58 items. When I try to add 59th item I am getting the follwing error.

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled
  Message=Value does not fall within the expected range.
  StackTrace:
       at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(String key, Category value, Boolean add)
       at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(String key, Category value)
       at TestReactive.com.beno.WP7Client.ViewModels.ListCategoriesViewModel.finalSelected(ListCategoriesModel items)
       at GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command.RelayCommand`1.Execute(Object parameter)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.ExecuteCommand()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
       at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
       at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

My Category Class

```
 public class Category
    {

        private String categoryID;
        private String categoryName;

        public String getCategoryID()
        {
            return categoryID;
        }

        public void setCategoryID(String categoryID)
        {
            this.categoryID = categoryID;
        }

        public String getCategoryName()
        {
            return categoryName;
        }

        public void setCategoryName(String categoryName)
        {
            this.categoryName = categoryName;
        }
}
```

Please let me know where I did mistake.

Comment: How do you define your `Category` type? Maybe duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18677510/c-sharp-dictionary-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range) question?

Comment: Now I found the Problem.The problem is key value is same for two items. That's why I am getting this error. All the data were dynamic. Is there any way add the values using same key in Dictionary?

Comment: No. Keys in a `Dictionary` have to be unique. You can, however, use lists or other collections as values to store multiple items per key.

Comment: Oh.. Thank you @MártonMolnár.. I will take look on this way.. Thanks for Knowledge sharing.. :-)..